# How to select and fill a region of similar colors in PHP GD?

Tags: php, gd, edge-detection, region, flood-fill

I am working in PHP+GD, trying to detect a polygon in an image and the flood fill it with a solid color.  I am trying to do something akin to the magic wand tool plus the paint bucket tool in photoshop: I have a pixel known to be in the interior of a polygon feature, and I want to find the edges of the feature and fill to those edges in a solid color.

I've tried using imagefilter($image, IMG_FILTER_EDGEDETECT); but it does create edges, but I don't see how to extract the connected edge as a polygon. Also, sometimes the edge detection is finding wood grain or paint variation and breaks up the polygon I want into smaller pieces.  I need to have it blend all those and treat the whole polygon as one connected region and make it a solid color.

I've attached a pair of images below:  a sample image to illustrate the kind of image that I am working with, and the kind of image I want to derive from it.

The reference image is:

[sample image 1 http://test.soundfit.me/snapshot-18201160.jpg](http://test.soundfit.me/snapshot-18201160.jpg)

As you can see there are two dowels in the image that are painted black on the top. Their edges roughly form elliptical polygons.  There are other dowels and cylinders of different colors and patterns in the background and floor that I want to ignore.

I want to transform this image so that these two roughly black polygons become filled solid black polygons, and everything else is flood filled to be solid white, as in this manually derived image.

[sample image 1 http://test.soundfit.me/blackcircles2.jpg](http://test.soundfit.me/blackcircles2.jpg)

I know the x,y position of at least 1 pixel within each polygon that is guaranteed to be in the interior  of that polygon. So if I could tell GD to create a polygon of the proximate region of a similar color, and if I could then flood fill the polygon all black, and finally flood fill everything that is not within that polygon with white, then I would have achieved my goal

But I am not sure how find create the edge vertices of the polygon that corresponds to the roughly black region. so I can flood fill it.

What steps would you take?

Comment: Hello! Do you have any code so far that you can post?

Comment: No, I don't have any code I can post so far. I've played around with imagefilter($image, IMG_FILTER_EDGEDETECT);
imagefilter($image, IMG_FILTER_CONTRAST, -255);
imagefilter($image, IMG_FILTER_GRAYSCALE);
But the aren't helping me.